# NSUInteger vs NSInteger, int vs unsigned, and similar cases

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, types

Anyone have the expertise to explain when to use NSUInteger and when to use NSInteger?

I had seen Cocoa methods returning NSInteger even in cases where the returned value will always be unsigned.

What is the fundamental reason? Is NSInteger or int strictly limited to if we want to represent negative value?

From NSObjCRuntime.h:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should also be aware of integer conversion rules when dealing with NSUInteger vs. NSInteger:

The following fragment for example returns 0 (false) although you'd expect it to print 1 (true):

```
NSInteger si = -1;
NSUInteger ui = 1;
printf("%d\n", si < ui);
```

The reason is that the [si] variable is being implicitly converted to an unsigned int!

See [CERT's Secure Coding site](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) for an in-depth discussion around these 'issues' and how to solve them.

Answer (score 24):

By default, an integer is assumed to be signed. In other words the compiler assumes that an integer variable will be called upon to store either a negative or positive number. This limits the extent that the range can reach in either direction. For example, a 32-bit int has a range of 4,294,967,295. In practice, because the value could be positive or negative the range is actually −2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647. If we know that a variable will never be called upon to store a negative value, we can declare it as unsigned, thereby extending the (positive) range to 0 to +4,294,967,295. So i would say, its okay to use NSInteger when you know that you have a restricted output range. I personally use NSUInteger if I needed to return really big positive only numbers

Comment: Nice answer and what I needed to know :)

Comment: What if I want to store -4,294,967,295 ? I cant use NSInteger then?

Comment: @Nil
long long int: -9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
unsigned long long int: 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. Pretty big amount to have it in your account :D

Answer (score 8):

If your method has a suitably restricted output range, you might as well use `NSInteger` since it's easier to type.  As you say, if you need to return negative numbers, `NSInteger` is the only game in town; I'd only use `NSUInteger` if I needed to return *really* big numbers for some reason.

Comment: For even bigger numbers, use NSDecimalNumber for 38 places of base-10 precision.

Comment: +1, @codewarrior, only if you can pass classes around, though.

Comment: I go the other way: I use NSUInteger at all times, except when I need negative numbers. Also, you mean objects, not classes; there are very few reasons to pass classes around, and even fewer reasons to pass the NSDecimalNumber class specifically.

Comment: I guess it really depends on our needs.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about cocoa specifically, but usually the only disadvantage of signed integers is they usually have half the maximum value as a unsigned int.  Such as about 2 billion instead of 4 billion for 32bit systems.  Generally this is not a big difference, since if you are dealing with values close to 2 billion, you probably would be just as worried about a 4 billion max in the same case, since it is still putting pretty close to an overflow with just a multiplication of 2 or 3.

Signed integers are usually preferred because the additional flexibility and fact that a signed integer can be used in almost all the scenarios an unsigned integer can plus all the additional scenarios it cannot where a negative is needed.

Unsigned might be preferred if you want to enforce positive only values.

Comment: I added the definitions of NSInteger and NSUInteger.

Comment: signed integers are sometimes used even when the normal range is positive if you want to be able to initialize a variable to an "invalid" value such as -1.

Comment: Interestingly, Swift, the replacement for Objective C, says to always use signed numbers when possible. *From the docs*:  
Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this is not the case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to be non-negative. A consistent use of Int for integer values aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference, as described in Type Safety and Type Inference.

Comment: I agree with this for consistency of usage