# iOS : NSInteger and NSUInteger comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, nsinteger, nsuinteger

Surprise!

I've a variable like this,

```
NSInteger index = 0;
```

I'm comparing it with one of subviews count (which returns `NSUInteger`) like this,

```
if((index-1) <= [[currentmonth subviews] count]) 
{
    NSLog(@"true");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"false");
}
```

> **This always giving false.**

but If I'll do like this,

```
if ((index-1) <= 42) {
    NSLog(@"true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"false");
}
```

> **This always giving true.**

I feel that, this because we can't compare `NSInteger` with `NSUInteger` correct?

I caught this issue, when I have a working solution based on this logic. ***But its not true at all.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found this, [NSUInteger vs NSInteger, int vs unsigned, and similar cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557209/nsuinteger-vs-nsinteger-int-vs-unsigned-and-similar-cases)

This answer gives the good explanations on this!

---

You should also be aware of integer conversion rules when dealing with NSUInteger vs. NSInteger:

The following fragment for example returns 0 (false) although you'd expect it to print 1 (true):

```
NSInteger si = -1;
NSUInteger ui = 1;
printf("%d\n", si < ui);
```

The reason is that the [si] variable is being implicitly converted to an unsigned int!

See [CERT's Secure Coding site](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) for an in-depth discussion around these 'issues' and how to solve them.