# Why doing minus operation for NSUInteger while comparing crashed?

Tags: objective-c

I'm comparing two `NSUInteger`, I kept getting crash thats says `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
NSUInteger index = [masterArray indexOfObject:object];
if (index != NSNotFound){
    if (index < [anArray  count] - 1 ){
        //Do something
    }
    else{
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Reading [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480412/ios-nsinteger-and-nsuinteger-comparison) of similar question, but I still can't figure this out. I've tried to cast and it still crash:

```
NSUInteger index = [masterArray indexOfObject:object];
if (index != NSNotFound){
    if (index < (NSUInteger)((int)[anArray  count] - 1) ){
        //Do something
    }
    else{
        //Do something
    }
}
```

However, without any minus operation, it works.

```
NSUInteger index = [masterArray indexOfObject:object];
if (index != NSNotFound){
    if (index < [anArray  count]){
        //Do something
    }
    else{
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `-[__NSCFNumber length]` crash in this code or in `//Do something`? Is the class of the result of `anArray[count - 1]` a `NSNumber` while you're expecting a `NSString`?

Comment: I think the crash happens in the ‘// Do something’ part. You are doing that if ‘index < [array count] - 1‘ and I think the array is empty. However, because it is unsigned, 0-1 wraps to a huge positive and you go down the wrong branch. Maybe change the compare to ‘index + 1 < [array count]’ and see what happens.

Comment: You guys are right, after rechecking my code based on the opinions, I found that `anArray` is an empty array on some instances, causing subsequent code to crash. Thanks! I'll be closing this post as it's not related to the question anymore.

Answer (score -1):

the array is not the problem.
See what happens in the following example.

```
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSLog(@"%@", i-1==NSUIntegerMax ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
//output: YES

NSLog(@"NSUIntegerMax=%lu", NSUIntegerMax );
//output: NSUIntegerMax=18446744073709551615

NSLog(@"%lu", i-1 );
//output: 18446744073709551615
```

so when array count is 0 and you subtract 1 you end up with the `NSUIntegerMax`.

You compare `array.count - 1` against a range of numbers that can't express  signed (negative) numbers.

`array.count` is a property of type `NSUInteger`.
so in the following scenario will come up

**when array.count == 0,**

```
array.count - 1 == 18446744073709551615 // not!! -1
```

your `if` statements will not work as expected unless you really wanted to compare to NSUIntegerMax.
As you discovered casting to integer may help you out..
you will want to

```
if (index < ((int)array.count) - 1) {
} else {
}
```

because casting `(NSUInteger)((int)array.count - 1)`
 is still 18446744073709551615 == NSUIntegerMax when array.count < 1

you could also go without casting for this solution

```
if (index + 1 >= array.count) {
} else {
}
```