# Objective c min max operation

Tags: objective-c, math

Can you explain me why this code:

```
NSInteger i = -1;
NSUInteger x = 1;
NSLog(@"min = %lu", MIN(i, x));
NSLog(@"max = %lu", MAX(i, x));;
```

prints
min = 1

max = 18446744073709551615

Comment: You are comparing objects of 2 different types... MAX and MIN internally cast the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare two different types: signed (NSInteger) and unsigned (NSUInteger). MIN/MAX convert all to unsigned integer.

Moreover, negative NSInteger is printed with %lu instead of %du. Therefore see a big number.

```
NSInteger i = -1;
NSUInteger x = 1;
NSLog(@"min = %ld", MIN(i, (NSInteger)x));
NSLog(@"max = %ld", MAX(i, (NSInteger)x));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `i` is actually being converted into an unsigned int implicitly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557209/nsuinteger-vs-nsinteger-int-vs-unsigned-and-similar-cases). As a result it rolls over to 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 0):

It is because i is being implicitly converted to an unsigned long.  It is part of the way xcode handles integer conversions.  Here is a similar post. [NSUInteger vs NSInteger, int vs unsigned, and similar cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557209/nsuinteger-vs-nsinteger-int-vs-unsigned-and-similar-cases)